# Grouping dates and records by weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using sql server 2008:

I have a query that count the total number of tasks and total number of completed tasks per day

I need to have the same logic per weeks (insted of days).
I don't necessary have a record for each day (does it matter ?, if so how can I insert an empty days records ?) .

The following is the current query for counting tasks per day:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, T.TaskEndDate)) AS 'EndDate',
    COUNT(T.TaskID)NumOfTasks,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T.TaskRecordsStatus = 2 THEN T.TaskID END) NumOfCompleteTasks
FROM 
    dwh.Bks_DWH_TaskRecords_V1 T
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, T.TaskEndDate))
ORDER BY 
    DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, T.TaskEndDate)) DESC
```

This is the query output (few lines as a sample):

```
End Date NumOfTasks NumOfCompleteTasks
2015-06-27 00:00:00.000 1   0
2013-09-17 00:00:00.000 1   0
2013-02-11 00:00:00.000 1   1
2013-02-07 00:00:00.000 4   0
2013-02-06 00:00:00.000 1   0
2013-02-04 00:00:00.000 1   0
2013-01-20 00:00:00.000 2   0
2013-01-19 00:00:00.000 1   0
2013-01-18 00:00:00.000 2   0
2013-01-17 00:00:00.000 5   0
```

This is the required result:

```
End Date NumOfTasks NumOfCompleteTasks
2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 10  0
2013-01-07 00:00:00.000 6   1
2013-01-14 00:00:00.000 0   0
2013-01-21 00:00:00.000 0   0
2013-01-28 00:00:00.000 7   3
2013-02-05 00:00:00.000 2   1
2013-02-12 00:00:00.000 0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT EndDate = Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, T.TaskEndDate), 0), 
       NumOfTasks = COUNT(T.TaskID),
       NumOfCompleteTasks = COUNT(CASE WHEN T.TaskRecordsStatus = 2 THEN T.TaskID END)
FROM 
   dwh.Bks_DWH_TaskRecords_V1 T
GROUP BY
    Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, T.TaskEndDate), 0)
ORDER BY 
    Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, T.TaskEndDate), 0) DESC
```

[**SQL-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bbbd1/1/0) with simplified data

This assumes that you want monday as first day of the week since date 0 is  `1900-01-01` which was a monday.

Comment: I should be ashamed of myself, it's so simple that it's ridiculous :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to use it?

```
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, T.TaskEndDate)))
```

Comment: getting the following error `'DAYOFWEEK' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(D, DATEDIFF(D, T.TaskEndDate, 0), 0) AS 'EndDate',
    COUNT(T.TaskID) NumOfTasks,
    SUM(CASE WHEN T.TaskRecordsStatus = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumOfCompleteTasks
FROM 
    dwh.Bks_DWH_TaskRecords_V1 T
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(D, DATEDIFF(D, T.TaskEndDate, 0), 0)
ORDER BY 
    DATEADD(D, DATEDIFF(D, T.TaskEndDate, 0), 0) DESC
```

For the weekly version change D in each DATEADD with Week